# Properties of Bloch wavefunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, crystals

I am reading the paper ["Some analytical results for the resistively shunted Josephson junction"](https://doi.org/10.1051/rphysap:019740090102500) by M.J. Renne & D. Polder (PDF is available [here](https://hal.science/file/index/docid/243750/filename/ajp-rphysap_1974_9_1_25_0.pdf)). The cornerstone of the research presented in paper is the set of properties of the following Schrodinger equation solution,
$$-\frac{d^2\psi}{d\tau^2}+V(\tau)\psi=0,\tag{*}$$
where $V(\tau)$ is the periodic function with known period $2\pi/\xi$.

The authors list the following properties:

1. There are two types of solutions. The first type is band functions, $$\psi_k(\tau)=e^{ik\tau}u_k(\tau),\quad \psi_k^*(\tau)=e^{-ik\tau}u_k^*(\tau).\tag{**}$$
   The second type is gap functions,
   $$\psi_{\mu,1}(\tau)=e^{\mu\tau}u_{\mu,1}(\tau),\quad \psi_{\mu,2}=e^{-\mu\tau}u_{\mu,2}(\tau).$$
2. In the extended zone scheme on the positive $k$-axis the energy $E$ is the continuous non-decreasing function of $k$ inside the Brillouin zone (energy bands) and it may have discontinuities at the edges of these zones (energy gaps)
3. The function $u_k$ describes a closed contour in the complex $u$-plane, the point $u=0$ does not lie inside or on this countour (except at the edge of a Brillouin zone)
4. Any linear combination of $\psi_k$ and $\psi_k^*$ which yields on the real axis a real solution of $(*)$ has an average number of zeros per unit interval on the real axis $k/\pi$ (it the consequence of 3)
5. All real solutions in energy gap at the edge of a Brillouin zone have the same number of zeros, $k/\pi$, where $k$ locates the edge of zone, $k=n\xi/2$ with integer $n$.

I clearly understand property 1, I can believe in property 2 (I can verify it using the numerics), but I cannot understand properties 3-5. It seems that I can check property 3 by considering (for simplicity) Mathieu equation and it really seems that $u_k$ corresponds to the closed contour in $u$-plane. But I would like to see a comprehensive discussion of properties 3-5, so: **how to prove properties 3-5?**

I am looking not for rigorous proof, but some references and key ideas that help to understand the property 3. If the property 3 is established, then properties 4 & 5 are quite easy to derive (I assume).

My attempt to understand property 3 was based on the Mathieu equation (it is one of the simplest examples of eq. $(*)$). I have used Wolfram Mathematica. I know that `MathieuC` corresponds to even periodic Mathieu function in Mathematica and I know that `MathieuCharacteristicExponent` corresponds to parameter $k$ in eq. $(**)$. I plot the ratio `MathieuC` over `MathieuCharacteristicExponent` with same parameters in comples plane (I use `ParametricPlot` and vary parameter $\tau$ from 0 to 100). The result is shown below

[image]

Here the horizontal axis corresponds to $\mathrm{Re}\,u_k(\tau)$, whereas vertical axis corresponds to $\mathrm{Im}\,u_k(\tau)$. Ok, I see that it seems indeed the closed contour. But I am still not sure that I interpret and understand property 3 in a correct way, because I do not understand how to make conclusions about zeros (propeties 4 & 5).

Comment: This might work better as a resource-recommendation type question.   As it stands it's multiple questions requiring detailed answers, which is very strongly discouraged here.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine I have added the mentioned tag. I do not see that this question requires multiple detailed answers. All the listed properties are related to each other. For instance, I explicitly write that prop. 4 is the consequence of prop. 3. So, I assume that resource-recomm/sketch of proof for prop. 3 will be enough.

Comment: Perhaps you could add that you just want an outline of the approach to the proof in your question to make that clear.  It's not that people have not posted detailed proofs from time to time, it's simply that it's rare and as written your question seems to ask for that (to me).  The site format isn't really designed for that.  Thanks for adding the tag, by the way.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine , I have stated explicitly that a sketch of proof or a reference is desirable, not a rigorours proof.

Comment: I'd already voted up, but i appreciate the effort.  Thanks.